# Get points on ellipse arc

Tags: ios, core-graphics

How to get points to adding identical intervals?

This code works for circle where theta increment by a fixed value

```
for (theta = 0 -> 360 degrees)
{r = ellipse_equation(theta);

x = r*cos(theta) + h;
y = r*sin(theta) + k;
}
```

But if increment is fixed for ellipse turns non identical intervals

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right to me:

```
x = r*cos(theta) + h;
y = r*sin(theta) + k;
```

Shouldn't that actually be

```
x = cos(theta) * h;
y = sin(theta) * k;
```

?

And could you please clarify what you mean by "identical intervals"?

Edit:
I don't think there is an 'easy' way to get what you want. Unlike a circle, an ellipse's circumference cannot be trivially calculated: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference, or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral